# Calculated columns bases on the past 3 months in Power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

First time trying to use M in power query... what I have is this table

[image: table]

I need to create two columns that per each row (combination of CD_Loja x CD_Produto )returns me the sum of QT_VENDA for that combination divided by the # of days in the past 3 months. The other column is pretty much the same but with the sum of  VL_VENDA_LIQ  Instead.

I.e: For the first row I want to sum up all QT_VENDA that matches CD_PRODUTO =1001930 AND CD_LOJA = 151 in the past 3 months (the DATE column has daily data) and divide it by the number of days in those 3 months.

Is there a way to do so ? And how do I go about this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of "the past 3 months"?   The past 90 days? Based on name of the month I am comparing to -- (June pulls all prior days in June + May + April, or perhaps June pulls all prior days in May + April + March?

Comment: Past 3 months would be something like today() - 90 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, M, something along these lines

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.Buffer(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DATA", type date}, {"CD_PRODUCTO", type text}, {"CD_LOIA", type text}, {"QT_VENDA", Int64.Type}, {"VL_VENDA_LIQ", Int64.Type}})),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type" ,"QT_VENDA_90",(i)=>List.Average(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type" , each [CD_PRODUCTO]=i[CD_PRODUCTO] and [CD_LOIA]=i[CD_LOIA] and [DATA] <= i[DATA] and [DATA] >= Date.AddDays(i[DATA] ,-90)) [QT_VENDA]), type number),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom" ,"VL_VENDA_LIQ_90",(i)=>List.Average(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type" , each [CD_PRODUCTO]=i[CD_PRODUCTO] and [CD_LOIA]=i[CD_LOIA] and [DATA] <= i[DATA] and [DATA] >= Date.AddDays(i[DATA] ,-90)) [VL_VENDA_LIQ]), type number)
in #"Added Custom2"
```

Comment: Gonna take a look and try it out

Comment: Adapted to my tables but the file size on the bottom right keeps increasing and the query never completes, all the files are past 1 Gb now (originally the source files had 200 mb)

Comment: well it is doing a bazillion calculations .. For every row, it has to filter all other rows and pick out the most recent 90,  That said, it is not adding rows unless something is wrong.  Try a sample data set?  Or in powerbi, a measure like https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Average-last-30-90-days-on-a-daily-basis/td-p/1087921

Comment: Added Table.Buffer   see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try a **Measure** like below-

```
your_expected_value = 

var current_row_data = MIN(your_table_name[DATA]) 
--I Guess the column name should be Date instead
var current_row_data_minus_90_day = MIN(your_table_name[DATA]) - 90 
var current_row_cd_produto = MIN(your_table_name[CD_PRODUTO])
var current_row_cd_loja = MIN(your_table_name[CD_LOJA])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[QT_VENDA]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[DATA] >= current_row_data_minus_90_day 
        && your_table_name[DATA] <= current_row_data
        && your_table_name[CD_PRODUTO] = current_row_cd_produto
        && your_table_name[CD_LOJA] = current_row_cd_loja
    )
)/90

--Here 90 used for static 3 month consideration
```

Comment: I dont think that works if you don't have data for every day of the year since it is always dividing by 90 instead of dividing by the count

Comment: been getting only blanks, trying to figure it out...

Comment: @TallesLessa getting any error? Please show the final output you are getting.